# Can't execute Electron app on other devices after packaging(edit: nfc library is the cause)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app that uses Vue.js.

I ran electron-packager and got a nice looking folder. When I run the executable on my own computer it works. The window is displayed, and everything works great.

However, if I run it at any other winx64 computer it fails.

No error is displayed, running through cmd doesn't display anything and background processes are started, but the window doesn't open.

So I thought maybe it's a dependency issue. However, I have both dependencies installed. I have googled for ages but cant find out what the issue is.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "electron-log": "^2.2.14",
    "electron-logger": "^0.0.3",
    "electron-packager": "^12.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "nfc-pcsc": "^0.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-config": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-momentjs": "^0.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.0-beta.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-debug": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "vue-devtools": "^3.1.9",
    "vue-loader": "^15.0.9",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
    }
```

Edit:

I found out the nfc-pcsc library i'm using is the root of my problem.. No idea why and how to solve it... Im gonna dig in a bit further. Any idea's wy?

Comment: On your other test device, are there 2 screens ? maybe the app is running on the other screen which is off (yes it happens ;)) Suggestion: try again in another computer or virtual machine.

Comment: Tried it on multiple pc's found out it has something to do with a "nfc-pcsc": "^0.6.2" i'm using still cant figure out whats wrong though ..

Comment: Please, show your command (eg in your package.json) how you package your app.

Comment: Using it globally but this is it: electron-packager ./ Aida --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon
=./dms-icon.ico